# In C, how do I find if there is a contradicting (negated) literal in a string?

Tags: c

```
//input: a -b -a. This should contradict as '-a' is negated version of a.
char*check;
for (int i = 0; i < this_element_of_arrayLength; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < this_element_of_arrayLength; j++) {

         if (this_element_of_array[i]) == 2) {   //checking if char (a or -a) is of 2 length   
              check = str_replace(this_element_of_array[i], "-", "");
         }

         if (check == this_element_of_array[j]) {
              printf("Contradiction");
              exit(0);
         }    
     }
}
```

I am essentially trying to check if there are any opposite (negations) of that literal and trying many ways can't seem to get it right. I am making all literals positive and checking each one if there is a match. I've moved things around a lot and have been on this for way too long but nothing seems to be working so my brain is dead. 
**If I delete the first if statement and don't switch them to positive it works**

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear, I'm afraid -- not to me, anyway. Are you parsing an expression? What are the "literals", numbers? Perhaps you could give an example input with expected output.

Comment: `str_replace(literal, "-", "")` will return the original literal if it doesn't contain any `-`. You need to check that it's negative first, before removing the `-`.

Comment: In C, you can't use `==` to compare strings, you have to use `strcmp()`.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful. It is not clear what any of that code is supposed to do. I see you are comparing `char *` values at one point in the code, so perhaps you should be comparing the string contents instead?

Comment: Is _[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(mathematical_logic))_ what you are referring to???  i.e. where a positive literal is just an atom (e.g., `x`).
    And a negative literal is the negation of an atom (e.g., `-x`), and are you asking if this _negated literal_ possibly embedded within the string, i.e. surrounded with other characters?  (provide some examples of actual input strings.)

Comment: Sorry guys its been a long day I didn't explain very well. I'm taking in a char array from a struct one by one and checking contradictions between all of them like (-a, a). I'm checking if its a negative by its the char is of 2 strlen. @Barmar i am comparing their ascii values.

Comment: So from your latest edit, is the _input_ in the form of `const char array[] = {"a -b -a"}:` ?  (or is it from `stdin`, or from reading values from the members of a struct?)

Comment: @ryyker kind of, its for a part of unit propogation and i need to see in a line of eg. (a -b c -d -a) whether any of those letters have an opposite or opposing letter. Opposing meaning negated

Comment: @ryyker yes it is reading values from an array in a struct. The code right now is not changing the 'check' variable everytime it loops so its only checking the rest of the array with the first letter

Comment: Are you trying to parse a string and extract variables and negations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words in your post (and comments) describe your intentions pretty well, but I was not able to follow some of the code.  (  This is where a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would have been beneficial. )   So working mostly off your problem descriptions...

Given the descriptions for the input string of potentially negated pairs of atoms (using the descriptions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(mathematical_logic)))  These assumptions/steps are used in the following implementation:

Assumptions:
string literals can be in the form:  `const char array[] = {"a -b c -d -a"}`
atom elements are at most two characters long (for illustration)
a *negation* occurs when base element type e.g `a` has a corresponding `-a`

Steps:

- determine *count* of elements in collection.
- create containers for *count* elements.
- parse elements from `string literal` into containers.
- loop through each element to find corresponding element of different length.

Here is a rough implementation that marks, and keeps count of *negation pairs* in a collection:

```
typedef struct {
    char ele[3];
    int len;
    bool negated;
}Ele;

int main(void)
{
    //const char array[] = {"-a -b -c -d -e -a -f -g -f -h -i -J k"};
    //const char array[] = {"a -b c -d e -a f g -f h i J k"};
    //const char array[] = {"a b c d a f g f"};
    const char array[] = {"-b -b -c -c a a"};//per comments

    char *tok = NULL;
    int countNegated = 0;

    int len = strlen(array);

    int count = 0;

    //count elements
   for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
       if(array[i] == ' ') count++;
   }
   count += 1;
   Ele e[count] = {0};//assuming form of either "-a" or "a" with single character 
   //separate array into searchable discrete strings
   int i=0;
   tok = strtok(array, " ");
   while(tok != NULL)
   {
       strcpy(e[i].ele, tok);
       e[i].len = strlen(tok);
       e[i].negated = FALSE;
       tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
       i++;
   }
   //With data encapsulated, walk through elements of collection
   //1-by-1, comparing each to those that are downstream to find 
   //same type but different length elements.  This is done using
   //a single loop, with a branche to accommodate the length of
   //each new element against all of its downstream elements:
   int j=0;
   for(i=0;i<count;i++)
   {
        if(e[i].len == 1)
        {
            for(j=i;j<count;j++)
            {
                if((e[j].len == 2) && strstr(e[j].ele, e[i].ele))
                {
                    countNegated++;
                    e[j].negated = TRUE;
                    e[i].negated = TRUE;
                }       
            }
        }
        else //len == 2)
        {
            for(j=i;j<count;j++)
            {
                if((e[j].len == 1) && strstr(e[i].ele, e[j].ele)) 
                {
                    countNegated++;
                    e[j].negated = TRUE;
                    e[i].negated = TRUE;
                }       

            }
        }
   }



    return 0;
}
```

Please leave a comment if this does not address all of your questions.

***Per Comments***:  [image]

Comment: thanks the strstr seems to work nicely. For some reason though, the loop seems to crash the program at the very end of all the iterations. Any idea why?

Comment: @thome.steve -  I tested for each of the input strings shown in the code toward the top.  I did not check all corner case however.  What input string are you using?

Comment: i used (-b -b -c -c a a), its the same problem with all cases where the for loop would continue out into the main method. I ''ve tried changing the loop max, and ive tried deleting the contents of the loop altogeher

Comment: in my case, i dont need to keep track of the number of negation cases but rather if there is one immediately stop the program. So for cases where there is no negation, it runs through all cases and stops the code at the end of the outer most loop

Comment: @thome.steve - I ran `const char array[] = {"-b -b -c -c a a"};`, in the same code base and I did not see a crash.  To solve this I would either have to see the actual code base you are using (in a minimally compilable example that includes the ability to reproduce the problem.) or you could run it in a debugger to see what the variable values are by stepping through the code.  If you choose to post your actual code, do it in a new question, then tag me in a comment and I will take a look.  For now, see my edit to show your new string, and an image of results in memory.